# CSS, image slider height with overlaying dots placement issue on responsive design

Tags: html, css, unslider

Probably overlooking something simple, but the issue is when the browser window width is small. The overlaying dots are not placed properly (bottom of the image).

**NOTE: If the "HEIGHT" attribute is removed from the HTML LI, then the images are not displayed.**
Playing with height:auto; in the HTML/CSS has the same result. Max-height has the same effect.

I want to remove the hard coded HTML style height and have the dots always appear at the bottom of the image, no matter the size.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/s3r8uuzz/

JavaScript files:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unslider.com/unslider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

CSS:

```
.banner ul { 
  list-style: none; /* Lose the dot */
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.banner li { 
  float: left; 
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.dots {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #353535;
  height: 35px;
  opacity: .7;
}

.dots li {
  position:relative;
  top:11px;
  left:-4px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  text-indent: -999em;
  border: 2px solid #bc9a6a;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
  -moz-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
  transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
}

.dots li.active {
  background: #3e245b;
  opacity: 1;  /* opacity of the inside dot (not the border) */
}


#slider{
  position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slider" style=""> 
    <div class="banner">
        <ul>
            <li style="background-image: url(http://cdn.nliphonedwwwghan.savviihq.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/500px1-580x375.jpg); height:350px;"><a href="/testing"></a></li>
            <li style="background-image: url(http://cdn.nliphonedwwwghan.savviihq.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/500px1-580x375.jpg); height:350px;"><a href="testing"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> 
<div>
    No matter the window size, this text should be directly under the image.
</div>
<script>
        // main image settings
        $('.banner').unslider({
                arrows: false,
                delay: 2000,
                fluid: true,
                speed: 1000,
                dots: true
        });

</script>
```

Comment: The height of the image container is fixed at 350px the image will respond inside that but the container will stay the same height

Comment: Yes, the height is fixed in the HTML. I want to delete that and have been unable to do so as the image is not displayed with that removed.

Comment: Dont use background images, put the image inside the li and the li height will wrap the image

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what I need fixed. Thanks for identifying the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using position:absolute for the dots, to have them properly positioned in its parent and not the body of the page, you will need to give the slider container, which currently has an id of 'slider', a relative positioning.

```css
#slider { position: relative; }
```

This will contain the absolute positioning of the dots within its parent container.

Comment: I believe this solution works nicely for a large image, but when you reduce the size of the image (like at smaller screen resolutions as stated in the question) the problem still remains unsolved.

Comment: @hungerstar I like this line of thinking and it fixed another side issue I had noticed. However I still cannot remove the fixed height in the HTML which will always keep it at the bottom of the image.

Comment: I have updated the question and FIDDLE to reflect your enhancement. Thanks.

Comment: @thefid `ru-pearls` posted the answer, I just made a simple edit to it. I did take a quick look and the `ul` that contains your `li` that end up being your image slides has a `height: 0px` set on it with the jQuery that runs it. It might be easier to find a different jQuery slider out there than forcing this one to do what you want.

Comment: I agree with @hungerstar, I'd find one which works to your requirements. I did some investigating and I think there is a bug somewhere. I looked on unslider's website and the <ul> that contains the <li> has the height, not the <li>'s individually. I think the solution is trying to assign the height to the <ul> and not the individual <li>'s.

Comment: Yes, Unslider uses the set height too... I was hoping there was an easier fix and not have to search for another slider since I already have a long time investment on the full size site and now coding to responsive.

Comment: There are many jQuery sliders out there, they are all very similar in how to set them up and function similar as well. Check this page out which has a run down of a few. [20 jQuery Sliders](http://www.vandelaydesign.com/awesome-jquery-sliders/)